# Google Maps rendering only a specific part of an image

Tags: php

What I've noticed about some sites that rely on heavy images (such as google maps)
is that they display a low-rez copy of an image and then when you focus on a certain section of that image they generate a high rez copy of the image. That seems easy enough. But what confuses is me is that they only render a specific section of that image and not the entire image. How do they go about doing this? (Rendering sections of an image at a time)

Answer (score 0):

Each "section of an image" is actually an individual image that is loaded separately from other images.

If you view your network details when browsing google maps, you'll see things like this

[image: A piece of google maps]

being transmitted, which is a small piece of the whole map that is displayed on the screen.